# Circle display on openlayers map (client-side vs server-side)

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, openlayers, mapserver, circle

I'm developing a webGIS website where I draw circles from two sources:

- a mapserver mapfile that "draws" them from PostGIS (red circles in image). The circles are created with ST_Buffer, eg

  ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(A B)', 4326), 0.072414686825054, 'quad_segs=32')

My mapfile serves in 4326 and 3857.

- Via Openlayers (blue concentric circles in image), either via

  var wgs84Sphere = new ol.Sphere(6378137);
  new ol.Feature(ol.geom.Polygon.circular(wgs84Sphere, GPS_pos_4326, i * 5 * 1852, 64).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));

or via turf, then creating an OL polygon, by using turf's destination function.

I understand that projecting a circle in "Google Mercator" **should** produce ellipses when not on the equator, so the behavior is expected.

But how could I do the same thing via OL?

[image: PostGIS/MapServer circles vs. Openlayers circles]

Comment: On the other hand, maybe circles should be drawn as real circles on web mercator...

Comment: +1 for the other hand

Comment: You were right. In web mercator circles must appear as circles (their only peculiarity being that they appear larger when moving to the poles).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in web mercator circles must appear as circles (their only peculiarity being that they appear larger when moving to the poles).
This is explained here: [Tissot's indicatrix](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/mapping/tissots-indicatrix-helps-illustrate-map-projection-distortion/)
and
for OL here: 
[OL Tissot's indicatrix example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/tissot.html)

The way I overcame the problem was to insert all my geometries into PostGIS in web mercator and have the mapfile read them as such.

For this I used ST_Translate, eg

```
ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT($lon $lat)', 4326), 3785), $rad, 'quad_segs=32');
```